# Changing the color of a geom_line based on a range. (THIS IS FOR THE PRODUCTION OF RESPIRATORS)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to color code a faceted line graph to change line colors when a data point is outside of a range. I want to have a green line for 13.7996 >= y >= 6.5896 and a red line for 13.7996 < y < 6.5896. [would like the lines for data points outside of the green lines to be red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOARD.png)

```
ggplot(ranged_32finish, aes(x=SN, y=Actual))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = 10.19462, color = "green3")+
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = 13.7996, color = "yellowgreen")+
  geom_abline(slope = 0, intercept = 6.5896, color = "yellowgreen")+
  facet_wrap(~Lot)+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Could you  provide a reproducible example [MRE]? The graphs look like satistical process control graphs - have you looked at package 'spc' https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spc/spc.pdf ?

Comment: Yes it is SPC. I will check out that package. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, it is done quite literally the way you described it.

Add the colour criterion to the aesthetic:

```
# EDITED to add the group aesthetic
aes(x=SN, y=Actual, colour=(Actual >= 6.5896 & Actual <= 13.7996), group=1 )
```

Setting group aesthetic puts the points back into the same group, this needed for a continuous line, since the colour aesthetic splits them into two groups.

And then set the colour scale values to your desired values:

```
scale_colour_manual(values=c('red', 'green'))
```

TRUE and FALSE are ordered alphabetically when matched to colour values, so FALSE takes the first colour, TRUE takes the second colour

Comment: when i do this it separates the data points into two separate lines of red and green. I need there to be one continuous line that changes color once it exceeds the limits. my knowledge of R and unfamiliarity with this certain data is probably limiting my ability to communicate this.

Comment: Add `group=1` to the aesthetic. This will force the lines to connect and prevent red from jumping across the green zone. But unless you have points on the actual threshold, the colours will extend to the nearest point past the threshold.

Comment: If the line colour extending past the threshold to the nearest point is undesireable, and having each threshold coincide with an actual point is unfeasible, consider instead the alternative of keeping the whole line black, and overlaying coloured points on it. If it gets too crowded, reduce the point size.

Comment: What if you have multiple groups? AKA you have multiple cuts : (Actual >= 6.5 & Actual <= 7) + (Actual >= 8 & Actual <= 10 ) + (Actual >= 11 & Actual <= 13)?

Comment: If you want a single line that changes colour along the way, the mechanism still applies, be it 2 colours or more.